# Laravel 5.7 admin panel login route

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to create admin panel with authentication as mysite/admin, so with this https://medium.com/employbl/easily-build-administrator-login-into-a-laravel-5-app-8a942e4fef37 tutorial i did it, but when i go to mysite/admin i get redirect to mysite/login and after successful authentication see mysite/admin page, but i want to see mysite/admin/login instead of mysite/login after i enter mysite/admin, how can i do this?

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin')
    ->middleware('is_admin')
    ->name('admin');
```

---

```
 class AdminController extends Controller
    {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function admin()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

---

```
class IsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

---

--- Add section ---

all i want is register for all at mysite/register, but login separate for users (and admins) at mysite/login and for (only) admins at mysite/admin/login with middleware check if user is admin as described before, how can i do this?

This is my routes:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin')
    ->middleware('is_admin')
    ->name('admin');
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login/', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Comment: show us ur routes and admin method code

Comment: Please show us your efforts on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix Auth::routes() like below.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'],function(){
    Auth::routes();
});
```

---

Manual registration of all the routes. First remove `Auth::routes()`

```
Route::get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login/', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register/', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register/', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: oh, no! register should stay as default for all users as mysite/register, but login is diff for users (mysite/login) and admins (mysite/admin/login); users will be redirect to mysite and admins to mysite/admin

Comment: It will make all the routes like register, login and forgot pass with prefix admin. If you don't want to do that then you can remove `Auth::routes()` and register all the routes manually. I have changed my answer please check. If it satisfy you then please give upvote.

Comment: I have changed my answer please check.

Comment: i add problem at -- Add section --- section

Comment: Can you please check this tutorial for that : https://hackernoon.com/laravel-multiple-authentication-80daa855322b

Comment: i've never seen so many diff quotes in one article, hard to straggle with that, so many errors...